# Value of type 'PHPhotoLibrary' has no member 'presentLimitedLibraryPicker' - Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

**Xcode 11.3.1**

**Use of undeclared type 'PHAccessLevel'**

**Value of type 'PHPhotoLibrary' has no member 'presentLimitedLibraryPicker'**

**I'm getting this error only if I try to compile against an actual device.** Tried with both iOS 14 and iOS 13 devices. Code compiles with simulators.
Tried clean building, cleaning Dervied Data and closing and reopening the project. But no luck

```
import Photos
import PhotosUI

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            let accessLevel: PHAccessLevel = .readWrite
            let authorizationStatus  = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: accessLevel)
            switch authorizationStatus {
            case .limited:
                var testVc = UIViewController()
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: testVc)
                //callBack(authorizationStatusAuthorised)
            case .authorized:
                //callBack(authorizationStatusAuthorised)
                var te = ""
            default:
                //callBack("")
                var test = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You’ll need Xcode 12 and target iOS 14+. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/3616113-presentlimitedlibrarypicker

Comment: @Rob Then how come the simulators work?

Comment: I have no idea. But the documentation is unambiguous, namely that this is an iOS 14 feature. You should use Xcode 12 to build apps using iOS 14 APIs.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would advise against “presenting” anything from `viewDidLoad`. You really should defer that until `viewDidAppear`...

Comment: @Rob Yes I know. This is just a dummy project I created to replicate the issue since I'm unable to post the original code here. Xcode 11 is being used by our Jenkins build. So it's a bit complicated to just switch to 12.

Comment: i have same issue on Xcode 13

Answer (score 3):

> Value of type 'PHPhotoLibrary' has no member 'presentLimitedLibraryPicker'

I got this error when used `import Photos` as a workaround try to use a single `import PhotosUI` (instead of `import Photos import PhotosUI` )

```
import PhotosUI
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an iOS 14 API feature (i.e. `PHAccessLevel`) while using iOS 13.x SDKs, as you're using Xcode 11.

You need Xcode 12 and above to make use of it.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phaccesslevel

Comment: @Heshan how would the simulators work? can you explain? If you're having build time errors as you are showing in your screenshot, it wouldn't even compile, let alone running it.

Comment: the moment I select a simulator, errors disappear and build works. If I select a device it shows the errors.